# How to share files between two web site type projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am currently developing a customer portal where a customer and representative can upload and download files.

In the representative project, I have created a `UploadedFiles` folder that has a `File` folder in it and then each folder is dynamically created which stores the file according in the id folder of that ticket.  Now Customer project is a website-type project:  I wanted to share the files between customer and Representative project.

P.S - I tried to use the add-as-link type but that option doesn't come on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an external storage . I would suggest Amazon S3 or Microsoft Azure or some other cloud storage.

OR

Create an FTP folder that can be accessed from both projects